# How to make an override for a function in a php file

Tags: php

I am using a module which is often updated by the developing company.

In one php file (cat_product_get.php) of this module is the here below function :

```
function getColSettingsAsXML()
```

Inside this function is the following code :

```
        {
            foreach($colSettings[$col]['options'] AS $k => $v)
            {
                $xml.='<option value="'.str_replace('"','\'',$k).'"><![CDATA['.$v.']]></option>';
            }
        }
```

Such code leads to the following warning :
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ../cat_product_get.php on line 317

Line 317 is the following :

```
foreach($colSettings[$col]['options'] AS $k => $v)
```

To fix the warning, I added one line as follows :

```
        if (is_array($colSettings[$col]['options']) || is_object($colSettings[$col]['options']))

        {
            foreach($colSettings[$col]['options'] AS $k => $v)
            {
                $xml.='<option value="'.str_replace('"','\'',$k).'"><![CDATA['.$v.']]></option>';
            }
        }
```

But at each module update, I have to amend again the cat_product_get.php.

I tried to convince many times the developer to add the suited line in his code.
But the developer refused to do it.

Is there a way to add somewhere an override to avoid the line addition at each module update ?

I am not a developer...

I thank you in advance for any reply.

Patrick

Comment: What do you mean you had to amend it?

Comment: From what you described, I assume you use some 3rd party package that contains the function you shared.
As you said about overwriting, you probably use composer to manage dependencies. If so, then you have possibility to fork the package, and make change in your copy, then declare to use it instead of original one.
Second option is to overwrite the function locally in a child class, but there are conditions that needs to be meet:
- it is part of class
- you have possibility to call newly created class directly, or declare it in dependency injection configuration

Answer (score 0):

If the function is just a plain function, then it can't be done in PHP. You can't have duplicate function names.

If it is a function in a class (aka a method), you can extend that class and just rewrite the function, and use your class.

```
class Person
{
   public function fixThisCrap()
   {
      return 'the wrong stuff';
   }

   // more functions 
}

class MyPerson extends Person
{
   public function fixThisCrap()
   {
      return 'the correct stuff';
   }

   // parent class functions will be available, no need to code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The function is not part of a class. Therefore I will continue to modify the cat_product_get.php file each time the developer makes an update.